# problems with xmlpoke in nant script when reading a semicolon in a string

Tags: asp.net, ant, web-config, nant, xmlpoke

I have a nant script that is trying to change a URL value in my web.config but Nant keeps throwing this error:

```
'=' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'. Line 1, position 80.
```

I traced it down to the semicolon in the URL of the nant script.  The reason I have a semicolon in the URL in the first place is because the web.config doesn't like ampersands (&).  So I had to replace & with `&amp;`.  Here's my web.config value:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="myUrl" value="http://www.google.com/whatever?id=myId&amp;fullScreen=1"/>
</appSettings>
```

I'm able to xmlpoke all the other "add keys" in the web.config but this one, so it's not an xpath issue.
Here's the nant script:

```
<property name="myUrl" value="http://www.google.com/whatever?id=123456&amp;fullScreen=2"/>

<xmlpoke 
   file="${config.file}"
   xpath="/configuration/appSettings/add[@key = 'myUrl']/@value"
   value="${myUrl}">    
</xmlpoke>
```

So the problem isn't with the semicolon in the web.config, but with the semicolon in the nant script.  I guess I need to somehow escape the semicolon in the nant script.  Anyone know how to do this or something else to get it to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's been 16 hours and not a peep from anyone.  Lucky for me I found the solution after a few hours of googling.

The solution is to use `&amp;amp;`.  I have no idea why the extra `amp;` but it worked.
So now my nant script looks like so:

```
<property name="myUrl" value="http://www.google.com/whatever?id=123456&amp;amp;fullScreen=2"/>
```

The credit goes to [Gary from the nant-users mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/nant-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg07956.html), which I just subscribed to :)